# Prove or disprove by counterexample that in every group, every element has a square root

Tags: abstract-algebra

For every $x \in G$, there is some $y \in G$ such that $x=y^2$. (This is the same as saying that every element of G has a square root)

Now, I'm not sure but I've been trying to think of counter-examples and I thought of the group of integers under multiplication.

Because if $x=5$ there is no integer $y$ where $y^2=5$

Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $G = \Bbb Q^*$ under multilplication. There is no $x \in \Bbb Q^*$ for which $2 = x^2$.

Comment: wouldn't you have to exclude 0 for it to be a group? for the rational example.

Comment: That's the job of "*". Though, I will have to exclude zero in the first one, so I'll just remove that.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can take the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and note that $\bar{0}+\bar{0} = \bar{1}+\bar{1} = \bar{0}$, so $\bar{1}$ is not a square.

Answer (score 3):

For a familiar counterexample, just take $(\mathbb{R}^*, *)$, the nonzero real numbers under multiplication.  Since negative numbers don't have square roots, this is a counterexample to the claim.

Answer (score 3):

(Z,+) also works.  (Odd numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer isn't quite right. Is the set of integers under multiplication a group? Try thinking about the integers under a different operation which makes it a group. Isn't it funny that $1/2$ is not an integer...

Comment: oh yes! I just realize the mistake.